# Running java from a bat file in such a way that path doesn't need to be specified

Tags: java, batch-file

I think I have seen this done, but am not sure where. What I want to do is to create a bat file I can package with my class files when sending to a friend to show them progress/ask advice on non programming matters. My friend is not very handy when it comes to code and doesn't like changing computer settings. Just using java myClass as a command line won't work here because although my friend does have java installed, he has not set his windows environment variables so his command prompt knows where to find java.

What kind of line would I need to add to my batch file to make it so it can compensate for problems like this?

Comment: Are you *sure* that he doesn't have it set in his path?  I think the installer does that for you.

Comment: Yes. When he types the run command java myClass in his command prompt, it says it doesn't recognize java. He does have java, he reinstalled it just to be sure. I had the same problem myself and fixed it by changing the environment variables (adding class and classpath to a couple boxes, I believe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a manifest file (manifest.txt):

```
Main-Class: com.mycompany.myapp.MyMainClass
```

Package your app as a jar:

```
jar cfm myjarfile.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

Create a batch file:

```
start myjarfile.jar
```

Comment: Looks good. Will try it... will report back in a minute. Edit - in response to your addition of *.class, I have txt files the program reads from as well as images. You sure I want that part?

Comment: Still doesn't work... same results as before. Tried quite a few variations with no change.

Comment: The use of 'jar' depends on your directory structure and files you want to include.  The above example assumes the current directory is the root of your classpath.  You may include the .txt files into the .jar IF you are reading them from the classpath, not directly (getResource vs FileInputStream/FileReader).  Just add "*.txt" to the jar command.  I'm guessing you are NOT reading from the classpath (getResource).

Answer (score 0):

If it is about sharing and running a single java file without jar dependencies. And you are only worried about the java runtime environment setup, then you can use online java code compilers and executors. Here is one:

http://javalaunch.com/JavaLaunch.jsp

You can google for more!

Comment: I tried launch4j which I think is the same kind of thing as this, and wasn't able to make it function as it needed a manifest file and such, in which my feeble attempts to create one failed... is this the only way? I will check out that link now.  EDIT -  this one looks considerably easier than launch4j. Just one problem - my program is 4000 lines of code in 10+  classes...

Answer (score 0):

Use an IDE, NetBeans or eclipse and package your files as a Jar file.. that can be executed directly and you do not need to worry about dependencies, other classes or libraries.

Comment: Never been able to get netbeans to work right with my project. It is my first and has gotten pretty disorganized in the gui class (luckily nothing in there is final). I will definitely do any future projects in netbeans but I think for this one that ship has sailed.